# Show bar with zero value in ChartJs v2

Tags: bar-chart, chart.js

I'm wondering is there any way to show in ChartJs (in bar chart) bars with zero value?

I mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vrg5cnk5/16/, so the second bar would be just blue border on level zero.

I used already this code:

```
ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    min: 0,
    suggestedMin: 0
}
```

but I'm not surprised it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply specify `minBarLength` in the dataset, with the minimum length in pixels the bars should have. See [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration).

**Working Example:**

```js
var $chartCanvas = $('myCanvas');
var barChart = new Chart(myCanvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Accepted Answer', 'Top rated answer', 'This Answer'],
        datasets:[{
            data: [0, 3, 10],
            minBarLength: 7,    // This is the important line!
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'helpfulness of answers to this questions'
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Best solution! I'm sorry I can't upvote it more than once.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest and most practical solution.

Comment: This solution should raise two questions:
First, one should be aware that this manipulates the height of a 0 value bar, thus manipulating the difference between this bar and others. You should check your requirements, if that's feasible.
Second, it's hard to hit this bar if your value is too low. Let's assume the min bar length is 7 and the other bars are at 10,000 - so getting a practical number here might be tricky.

Comment: @Baccata - "Let's assume the min bar length is 7 and the other bars are at 10,000" - the 7 in the example refers to pixel height, not bar value.

Answer (score 16):

After dig into the plugin system, if you using Chart.js >=2.5, you can write a plugin to achieve it. Here is an example to draw a line when data is zero.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
const zeroCompensation = {
  renderZeroCompensation: function (chartInstance, d) {
      // get postion info from _view
      const view = d._view
      const context = chartInstance.chart.ctx

      // the view.x is the centeral point of the bar, so we need minus half width of the bar.
      const startX = view.x - view.width / 2
      // common canvas API, Check it out on MDN
      context.beginPath();
      // set line color, you can do more custom settings here.
      context.strokeStyle = '#aaaaaa';
      context.moveTo(startX, view.y);
      // draw the line!
      context.lineTo(startX + view.width, view.y);
      // bam！ you will see the lines.
      context.stroke();
  },

  afterDatasetsDraw: function (chart, easing) {
      // get data meta, we need the location info in _view property.
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0)
      // also you need get datasets to find which item is 0.
      const dataSet = chart.config.data.datasets[0].data
      meta.data.forEach((d, index) => {
          // for the item which value is 0, reander a line.
          if(dataSet[index] === 0) {
            this.renderZeroCompensation(chart, d)
          }
      })
  }
};
```

and here is how to add the plugin to Chart.js

```js
var chart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [zeroCompensation]
});
```

The offcial document is not clear about their plugin API, you may console.log to find what you want.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to configure chart.js to do this, but you could use a **hack** instead.  Just set your value for the 0 bar to a really small number like 0.1.

```
data: [2, 0.1, 3, 1]
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jordanwillis/xe97vca6/1/) forked from yours.

If you are using tooltips, then you would have to also add some logic so that the tooltip for that bar still displays a value of 0. You can do this using the `label` callback.

```
label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
  var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
  var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];

  if (value === 0.1) {
    value = 0;
  }

  return label + ': ' + value + ' %';
}
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jordanwillis/fp96jc1q/2/) putting it all together.

Comment: I'm using callbacks for custom tooltips, code: https://jsfiddle.net/xe97vca6/3/

    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
            var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
            return label + ': ' + value + ' %';
        }
    }

If you could show me the way to customize it your way to show 0 - it would be great!

Comment: thanks, works great - of course you have to manipulates values and borderWidth to get best result, but it's no problem

Comment: I've found solution that needs manipulating core library - it also works but modifies Chart.js source - maybe someone would like to choose this

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3915

Comment: This can be done with the latest version of Chart.js easily with `options`. Find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58002951/4842112

Comment: Check answer from @talz, it works like a charm!, minimum size must be put into data set: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65796691/5810474

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simplest way to do this in V3 chart js

```
Chart.defaults.datasets.bar.minBarLength = 5;
```

Comment: This saved me so much hassle and time!

Comment: This one worked the best for me.

Comment: And the online documentation for 'minBarLength':
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

Answer (score 3):

If you struggle with this, here's what I came up with. It is similar idea to Li Jinyao, but in addition, you would get click and hover events (tooltip) working for whole bar.
I value is close to 0 but negative, the bar will show on negative side of x axis - you can easily get rid of it if that's not what you want to do.

```
const zeroCompensation = {
id: 'zeroCompensation',

beforeDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
    const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0)
    forEach(meta.data, d => {
        const barHeight = d._view.base - d._view.y;
        if(Math.abs(barHeight) < minBarHeight /* I used value 5 */) {
            d._view.y = d._view.base - minBarHeight * (Math.sign(barHeight) || 1);
        }
    });
}};
```

and add it to plugins:

```
plugins: [zeroCompensation]
```

Keep in mind that this will work for values close to 0, not only 0. If you want it only for zeroes, you can change contents of if condition to:

```
chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[index] === 0
```

This is what Li Jinyao used in his answer.
Hope that helps. 

Edit: I wanted to highlight that this solution works regardless of values spread. Answer marked as solution will not work as intended if there are some high values in data set - 0.1 will render same as 0 in that case.

Comment: I used this variation of your code:
const minBarHeight = 2;
export const zeroCompensation = {
    id: 'zeroCompensation',

    beforeDatasetsDraw: function(chart: any) {
        const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0)
        meta.data.forEach( (d:any) => {
            const barHeight = d._view.base - d._view.y;
            if(Math.abs(barHeight) < minBarHeight) {
                d._view.y = d._view.base - minBarHeight * (Math.sign(barHeight) || 1);
            }
        });
    }};

Comment: Cool that someone found it useful.

Comment: Indeed, it works great for vertical bar. When i adapted it specifically for horizontal bar chart, I get the bar I want but charts.js repaints a split second after and brings it back to zero width. I tried all draw-related lifecycle hooks and it still repaints it back to zero width

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over this questions because I had a similar problem: The type of my Chart.js chart was '**horizontalBar**' and for some datasets (where no zero values was present across the dataset) the horizontal bar did not start with 0 rather with the lowest value from the dataset.

I tried to figure out a solution and came up with following entry in the **options** object while creating the charts:

```
ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true,
                  mirror:false,
                  suggestedMin: 0,
                  suggestedMax: 100
}
```

However that did not work as expected although all posts said it works that way.
After further investigation and reading of the Chart.js documentation I found the solution. The reason the further step did not work was following I found in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html):

> However, any options specified on the x axis in a bar chart, are applied to the y axis in a horizontal bar chart.

So I just changed my options object to hold the proper configuration for the **xAxes** and it worked.

For those who are interested here is the the whole code I used for creating the horizontal bar chart with y-axis starting always at zero:

```
this.chart = new Chart(
    ctx,
    {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: this.data.chartdata,
        options: {
          scales: {
              xAxes: [{ 
                stacked: false,
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true,
                  mirror:false,
                  suggestedMin: 0,
                  suggestedMax: 100
                } 
              }],
              yAxes: [{ 
                stacked: true
              }]
          },
          scaleBeginAtZero : true,
          // important here to use () =>
          // to keep the scope of this
          onClick: (e) => {
            var actChart : Chart = this.charts[trialId];
            var element =
              actChart.getElementAtEvent(e);

            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2019 Update

This can be done easily as below.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ...
    options: {
        ...
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
);
```

You can find this in Chart.js documentation https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: This does not seem to work. It does not draw any line.

Comment: @rwwagner90 Did you try adding the full object from https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ . I have added only a partial code to highlight the important part - ` ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }`

Comment: This does not seem to be related to the question. `beginAtZero` has a different meaning than what the asker is looking for: *"if true, scale will include 0 if it is not already included."*
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html