# Start bar-chart at 0 using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a bar chart which use ChartJS that shows data. Based on the bar chart, I have the data: `15, 2, 0, 11`.

I can see all of these data in the bar, except 0. Is there a possibility to start the bar chart on 0, so I can also see the data for the fourth column in the bar chart?

```
options: {
  legend: { display: false },
  scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          display: false,
      }],
      xAxes: [{
          display: true,
      }],
  },
  title: {
    display: false,
  }

}
```

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: You will never see a physical bar for data with a value of `0`. Think about it - the absence of a bar in your chart tells the viewer that the value for that column is `0` - even if the Y-Axis were to start at a number below zero. If the viewer sees a bar there, they'll think it's a value greater than `0`. Then when they hover over it and see `0`, they'll be all sorts of confused.

Comment: Your right about it. But a bar that is completely empty doesnt look good. I also changed the `display` for `xAxes` to false. The bar chart looks when there is data in it. If there is no data I get just an empty area on my page

Comment: Still not fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of working, finally i found a soulution. There is no chartjs configuration to do it and you have to draw it your self. Let do it in `onComplete` function

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var datasets = [15, 2, 0, 11];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'value',
      backgroundColor: '#F00',
      data: datasets
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    animation: {
      onComplete: function() {
        var dataSet = myChart.getDatasetMeta(0);
        dataSet.data.forEach(elm => { 
          if (datasets[elm._index] == 0) {
            ctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
            ctx.fillRect(elm._model.x - elm._view.width / 2, elm._model.y - 1, elm._view.width, 2);
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="canvasChart" id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes It worked. Thanks. Do you know how I can define multiple colors for the bars? Now the `ctx.fillStyle = '#F00';` Is it possible to define multiple colors for this? Like: `ctx.fillStyle = "#26B99A", "#8cb926","#ede92d","#b96f26","#b92626"`


ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';

Comment: ctx.fillStyle is placed in foreach loop. So you only can set color for one bar at a time. To get the bar background use: `ctx.fillStyle = elm._model.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 4):

You can try `beginAtZero:true` config option.

```
options: {
  legend: { display: false },
  scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          display: false,
          ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
          display: true,
      }],
  },
  title: {
    display: false,
  }
}
```

Comment: With `beginAtZero:false,` the bar starts on 0. But 0 is not displayed on the bar

Answer (score 1):

Because your Y-axis values starts from 0 to something. So, if your value is 0 in X-Axis than it would be null and won't show you bar of 0. So, if you want 0 to appear in chart your starting point should be less than the 0.

Comment: So it must start at -1?

Comment: yes, as your need it should start from -1 or less than that.

Comment: And how can I make it start on -1

Comment: I am using chart.js

Comment: Not sure but you can try as : beginAtZero:false  and add some min value like min:  -2   or less.

Comment: With `beginAtZero:false,` and `min: -2` the bar starts on 0. But 0 is not displayed on the bar

Comment: than am sorry if I would know about this than I will inform you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you said you were using chartsjs. This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042242/3513171).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, chart will start with zero.

```
   options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```